# Ubuntu 12.4 LTS WiFi disabled

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

```
aliandena@aliandena-HP-510-Notebook-PC-RU962AA-ABU:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
aliandena@aliandena-HP-510-Notebook-PC-RU962AA-ABU:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Channel:0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=off   Sensitivity=8/0  
          Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

aliandena@aliandena-HP-510-Notebook-PC-RU962AA-ABU:~$ 
Helpline.
```

Using a paid for installation DVD of Ubuntu 12.4 LTS 32 Bit I did a clean install (XP deleted during install) on my **HP 510 Notebook** The download was successful and the operating system is working well, my router is connected via an Ethernet cable as the WiFi has been **Hard Blocked** during the installation.
The HP 510 Notebook has an on/off push button which is always "blue" when WiFi is enabled but now does not respond when pressed.

I have been unable to resolve this problem despite several attempts using various methods from
other Ubuntu users who also had this same glitch.

I would appreciate your advice on a remedy for my disabled WiFi.

Thank you,
           Al Smith

My apologies for my lack of knowledge in all things Ubuntu.

Having had a speedy reply to my above question I now need to supply my adviser with an image showing the results from his request for more information. The image/screenshot from my "terminal" has to be added to this edited question but I am at a loss as to how it can be transferred or uploaded.
I would be obliged if you would be as kind as direct me on the process.

---

I have attached the information from my "terminal" after having run the two commands that you
advised, it appears at the very start of this page

Thank you again for your advice and continuing assistance. -- Al Smith

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these two terminal commands: rfkill list all and also: iwconfig Thanks.

Comment: Al, we don't need the image, if you can copy and paste the text from the terminal into your question that will work too!